# Combining Mapbox GL JS plugin with another SQLite-based plugin (Cordova)

Tags: mapbox, spatialite, sqlite, mapbox-gl-js, cordova

I'm creating an App with Cordova. For this I want to use Mapbox GL JS for using offline maps and a SpatiaLite database for storing additional spatial data.

The [mapbox-gl-cordova-offline](https://github.com/oscarfonts/mapbox-gl-cordova-offline) plugin requires the [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext) plugin to work properly. To access the SpatiaLite database I want to use the plugin [cordova-spatialite-storage](https://github.com/DisyInformationssysteme/Cordova-spatialite-storage). I cannot use cordova-sqlite-ext for this because it only supports standard SQLite functions and not spatial functions, which my app also requires. However, apparently, I cannot use two separate SQLite plugins as the app can only recognize one ([see here](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext/issues/67#issuecomment-339732881)).

How do I go about combining the Mapbox GL JS plugin with another SQLite-based plugin? Alternatively, is it somehow possible to use SpatiaLite functions in a standard SQLite database?